# Why was this question considered "offtopic" and closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions, specific-question

[How can I install the Buzz bundle on Symfony 2.2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597772/symfony-2-install-sensiobuzzbundle/15597866#15597866)

Just out of curiosity, how come a question about symfony is offtopic on a programming site?

Comment: Well, even if it weren't offtopic, it would be "Not a real question" as it's just asking for an entire installation tutorial as it doesn't list any specific problems or ask any specific questions, it just asks for someone to explain an entire topic.  Such questions are too broad to be SO questions.  It's possible some of the users also voted to close for that reason, just not a majority.  If it was re-opened, it would just get closed again for another reason.

Comment: @Servy The "entire topic" in this instance is the 4 sentences in [Bogdan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15597866/99456). Yeap, that's all there is to it, nothing broad about it. Downvotes would make sense (lack of research), but the closure doesn't, not really.

Comment: @Yannis Well, two of his four sentences are "go to this link here and do all of the stuff it says there," so it's not really *just* four sentences.

Comment: @Servy Take a closer look. The link is to the repository that's already linked to in the question, we can assume the asker has already read it. And the answer doesn't really say "do all of the stuff it says there", it says "do step 3" (the "onward" is a bit misleading, step 3 is the last step).

Comment: It may just be my opinion, but questions related to the installation process of a tool  are fine as it relates to "Software development tools". The "could somebody walk me through?" ending implies vagueness, which could possibly justify the closing of the question, but if it's a specific answer, the OP probably had a specific question and just didn't know. I think the question should have just been edited to remove the vague ending.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy I tried to do just that, but apparently [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2305705) was "incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post". .. <sigh>

Comment: If I was more knowledgeable of the subject I'd give it a try. I suppose no person/system can be perfect, but it always stinks when you remember that, or see it in action. @Yannis

Comment: @MisterMelancholy Heh, I've resubmitted the edit, and this time it went through. Also, the question was re-opened.

Answer (score 9):

No idea why the question was closed. The question essentially boils down to:

> I'm trying to install a web framework's module. The suggested way in the docs isn't working with the current version of the framework. Help!

That's a concrete, specific and answerable question, about [something that's unique to the programming profession](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> ... if your question generally covers ... practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

I can only speculate, but I suspect the close voters thought the question was asking about installing some random non programming specific tool, which would make the question more appropriate for Super User. In any case, the closure is incorrect. It happens, we can't get it right every time.

Answer (score 5):

I have reopened the question after a fairly substantial edit was made to clean it up.

If you see a question like this the best approach is to edit it in to shape and then cast a reopen vote (if you are able) or maybe flag it for moderator attention (if you can't).

Edited <strike>closed</strike> on-hold questions should put them in the reopen queue as well.

Answer (score -3):

The question is not "actually" about Symphony. The OP is asking advice on how to install X. Stack Overflow deals with programming problems, not the errors you face while installing something.

It was closed as off-topic as the OP should instead have asked this on the application's own forums or help-desk.

Comment: "The OP is asking advice on how to install X." X in this case is a Symfony bundle...